# Cannot connect a Gateway or Microservice to the JHipster Registry. Jhipster v5.8.2

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I'm having issues connecting a Gateway or Microservice to the Jhipster-registry using Jhipster's UAA. No custom code, or entities yet, just trying to get the generated applicaitons running.

I get the following error, basically the tokenInfoUri is not set and it can't create the `ResourceServerProperties` bean. But what I've gathered from reading the docs is that it doesn't need to be set?

```sh
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\salom\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.5\liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/salom/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.5/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.
jar
18:09:23.012 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
18:09:23.017 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /sprin
g-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter/target/classes/]
18:09:23.018 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/git/marqzman-tech/mirco/gateway/target/classes/]

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 2.0.8.RELEASE ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2019-04-29 18:09:29.529  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.marqzman.example.gateway.GatewayApp  : The following profiles are active: dev,swagger
2019-04-29 18:09:32.720 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.e.gateway.config.AsyncConfiguration  : Creating Async Task Executor
2019-04-29 18:09:35.229  WARN 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-04-29 18:09:40.293 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.e.gateway.config.WebConfigurer       : Registering CORS filter
2019-04-29 18:09:40.433  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.e.gateway.config.WebConfigurer       : Web application configuration, using profiles: dev
2019-04-29 18:09:40.435  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.e.gateway.config.WebConfigurer       : Web application fully configured
2019-04-29 18:09:40.554 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.e.gateway.config.CacheConfiguration  : Configuring Hazelcast
2019-04-29 18:09:40.590 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.e.gateway.config.CacheConfiguration  : Configuring Hazelcast clustering for instanceId: gateway
2019-04-29 18:09:40.591 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.e.gateway.config.CacheConfiguration  : Application is running with the "dev" profile, Hazelcast cluster will only work with localhost instances
2019-04-29 18:09:40.670  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2019-04-29 18:09:41.318  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-04-29 18:09:41.319  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-04-29 18:09:41.575  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2019-04-29 18:09:41.576  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2019-04-29 18:09:42.152  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2019-04-29 18:09:42.665  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2019-04-29 18:09:42.665  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2019-04-29 18:09:42.666  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2019-04-29 18:09:42.667  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2019-04-29 18:09:42.667  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2019-04-29 18:09:42.668  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2019-04-29 18:09:42.669  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2019-04-29 18:09:42.915  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2019-04-29 18:09:42.918  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 5
2019-04-29 18:09:42.922  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 12
2019-04-29 18:09:42.928  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1556579382926 with initial instances count: 1
2019-04-29 18:09:43.001  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.9.4] Picked [127.0.0.1]:13781, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=13781], bind any local is true
2019-04-29 18:09:43.018  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Hazelcast 3.9.4 (20180420 - b8001d5) starting at [127.0.0.1]:13781
2019-04-29 18:09:43.019  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Copyright (c) 2008-2018, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2019-04-29 18:09:43.019  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version: 1
2019-04-29 18:09:43.315  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.s.i.o.impl.BackpressureRegulator     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Backpressure is disabled
2019-04-29 18:09:43.954  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Creating TcpIpJoiner
2019-04-29 18:09:44.162  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Starting 8 partition threads and 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2019-04-29 18:09:44.165  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
2019-04-29 18:09:44.172  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] [127.0.0.1]:13781 is STARTING
2019-04-29 18:09:44.193  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.system                     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Cluster version set to 3.9
2019-04-29 18:09:44.195  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4]

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
        Member [127.0.0.1]:13781 - e134aa74-39af-454e-aac9-6190ab4bad8b this
]

2019-04-29 18:09:44.233  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] [127.0.0.1]:13781 is STARTED
2019-04-29 18:09:44.271 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.e.gateway.config.CacheConfiguration  : Starting HazelcastCacheManager
2019-04-29 18:09:44.536 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.e.g.config.LiquibaseConfiguration    : Configuring Liquibase
2019-04-29 18:09:44.587 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Loading driver configuration via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
2019-04-29 18:09:44.588 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/gateway
2019-04-29 18:09:44.614 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to localhost:5431
2019-04-29 18:09:44.623 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.624 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.734  WARN 3896 --- [eway-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2019-04-29 18:09:44.739 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/gateway
2019-04-29 18:09:44.741 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to localhost:5431
2019-04-29 18:09:44.752 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.753 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.831 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/gateway
2019-04-29 18:09:44.841 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to localhost:5431
2019-04-29 18:09:44.847 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.855 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.867 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/gateway
2019-04-29 18:09:44.867 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to localhost:5431
2019-04-29 18:09:44.875 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.876 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.885 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/gateway
2019-04-29 18:09:44.886 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to localhost:5431
2019-04-29 18:09:44.890 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.891 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.906 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/gateway
2019-04-29 18:09:44.907 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to localhost:5431
2019-04-29 18:09:44.914 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.915 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.923 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/gateway
2019-04-29 18:09:44.925 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to localhost:5431
2019-04-29 18:09:44.945 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.948 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.976 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/gateway
2019-04-29 18:09:44.977 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to localhost:5431
2019-04-29 18:09:44.984 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:44.985 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:45.001 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/gateway
2019-04-29 18:09:45.001 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to localhost:5431
2019-04-29 18:09:45.014 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:45.014 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:45.029 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/gateway
2019-04-29 18:09:45.030 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to localhost:5431
2019-04-29 18:09:45.048 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:45.050 DEBUG 3896 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 65,536
2019-04-29 18:09:45.238  INFO 3896 --- [y.HealthMonitor] c.h.internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor   : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] processors=8, physical.memory.total=31.8G, physical.memory.free=7.5G, swap.space.total=44.9G, swap.space.free=4.6G, heap.memory.used=
383.6M, heap.memory.free=713.9M, heap.memory.total=1.1G, heap.memory.max=7.1G, heap.memory.used/total=34.95%, heap.memory.used/max=5.30%, minor.gc.count=9, minor.gc.time=132ms, major.gc.count=3, major.gc.time=254ms, load.process=85.94%, load.system=89.65%, load.sys
temAverage=n/a thread.count=61, thread.peakCount=61, cluster.timeDiff=0, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operations.s
ize=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, operations.completed.count=1, executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0, executor.q.cluster.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.running.count=0, operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%
, operations.pending.invocations.count=0, proxy.count=0, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=0, client.connection.count=0, connection.count=0
2019-04-29 18:09:46.031 DEBUG 3896 --- [eway-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase has updated your database in 1294 ms
2019-04-29 18:09:46.600  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.h.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory        : Starting up HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
2019-04-29 18:09:46.602  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.h.i.IHazelcastInstanceFactory        : Using existing HazelcastInstance [gateway].
2019-04-29 18:09:48.037  INFO 3896 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_GATEWAY/gateway:7bd9d6c91e1e73eae650ab0eb809f25e - Re-registering apps/GATEWAY
2019-04-29 18:09:48.038  INFO 3896 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_GATEWAY/gateway:7bd9d6c91e1e73eae650ab0eb809f25e: registering service...
2019-04-29 18:09:48.163  INFO 3896 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_GATEWAY/gateway:7bd9d6c91e1e73eae650ab0eb809f25e - registration status: 204
2019-04-29 18:09:48.322 DEBUG 3896 --- [  restartedMain] .m.e.g.c.o.OAuth2JwtAccessTokenConverter : Public key retrieved from OAuth2 server to create SignatureVerifier
2019-04-29 18:09:50.273  WARN 3896 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating be
an with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tokenServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$RemoteTokenServicesConfiguration$TokenInfoServicesConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter
 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerProperties': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.validation.BindExce
ption: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'resourceServerProperties' on field 'tokenInfoUri': rejected value [null]; codes [missing.tokenInfoUri.resourceServerProperties.tokenInfoUri,missing.tokenInfoUri.tokenInfoUri,missing.tokenInfoUri.java.lang.String,missing.tokenInfoUri]; argumen
ts []; default message [Missing tokenInfoUri and userInfoUri and there is no JWT verifier key]
2019-04-29 18:09:50.290  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.h.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory        : Shutting down HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
2019-04-29 18:09:50.291  WARN 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.h.i.IHazelcastInstanceFactory        : hibernate.cache.hazelcast.shutdown_on_session_factory_close property is set to 'false'. Leaving current HazelcastInstance active! (Warning: Do not disable Hazelcast
hazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled property!)
2019-04-29 18:09:50.294  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] [127.0.0.1]:13781 is SHUTTING_DOWN
2019-04-29 18:09:50.298  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Shutting down connection manager...
2019-04-29 18:09:50.300  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Shutting down node engine...
2019-04-29 18:09:50.308  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.instance.NodeExtension     : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Destroying node NodeExtension.
2019-04-29 18:09:50.309  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] Hazelcast Shutdown is completed in 11 ms.
2019-04-29 18:09:50.310  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [127.0.0.1]:13781 [dev] [3.9.4] [127.0.0.1]:13781 is SHUTDOWN
2019-04-29 18:09:50.326  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.e.gateway.config.CacheConfiguration  : Closing Cache Manager
2019-04-29 18:09:50.338  INFO 3896 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2019-04-29 18:09:50.344  WARN 3896 --- [  restartedMain] .s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating
bean with name 'eurekaInstanceConfigBean': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
2019-04-29 18:09:50.390 ERROR 3896 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties@538c2e1c failed:

    Property: resourceServerProperties.tokenInfoUri
    Value: null
    Reason: Missing tokenInfoUri and userInfoUri and there is no JWT verifier key


Action:

Update your application's configuration

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-29T18:09:50-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install latest version of JHipster (v5.8.2)
2. Generate the UAA app
3. Generate the Gateway app
4. Start the registry
5. Start the UAA (It successfully registers)
6. Start the Gateway
7. See it fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: I upgraded the generator to 6.0.1 and the issue has been resolved.